# select all div elements in DOM after an element?

Tags: jquery, find

I'm running something like this to select all div elements in DOM (and this is good for me):

```
var $mySelection=$("#wrapper").find('div').not("#main-content, #etc")
```

How would I select all div elements in the DOM after a certain div instead?

Comment: All `divs` including nested ones? Or just ones that are siblings of the starting point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really mean *all* `<div>` elements in the DOM after a starting point, you would first need in find nested ones of all its next siblings, then you'd need to get the actual next siblings that are `<div>` elements.

```
var divs = $('#wrapper').nextAll().find('div');
divs = divs.add('#wrapper ~ div');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div#id').nextAll(selector);
```

[.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is wrong, because it only looks at following siblings of the element. But what if the div he wants is a following sibling of a **parent** element of the referenced div?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [next siblings selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/)

```
$('div#wrapper ~ div')
```

I also notice in your example you have `.not("#main-content, #etc")` .  I belive you are trying to exclude these siblings.  If so this is an easy way using the [not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$('div#wrapper ~ div:not(#main-content, #etc)')
```